# Django - view JSON login_required

Tags: python, django, json, security, http-status-codes

I have a view that is being called with ajax and returns JSON.

I'd like it to require authentication.

```
@login_required
def my_view(request):
    data = some_data
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')
```

Ideally, if I'm not authenticated this view should return a HTTP status *401 Unauthorized* or something similar, so my javascript can correctly interpret the response.

Is it a good practice for requiring authentication on Ajax requests ?
If yes, how could I get this HTTP status from the `@login_required` decorator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. whether it is a good practice or not depends on what the resource the ajax request is requesting
2. you don't have to use `login_required` decorator, you can simply check the credentials inside `my_view` instead. And if check fails, return 401.
3. If you have quite a few resources and you want to build a REST API on top of it for Ajax purpose, consider using a framework such as [Tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org).

Comment: Tastytie seems interesting, I will check it when my application will grow. Maybe I should create my decorator like `login_required_ajax`

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY Yes, declare a custom decorator is a good idea in this case.